# Sharing cached resources between java classes

Tags: java, caching

I have three classes, testContainer.java, recurringTest.java and databaseHelper.java

testContainer class runs only once and stays alive while recurringTest runs again and again.

```
public class testContainerA extends someExternalClass {
    public void initialize() {
        databaseHelper.getResoucefromDB(A)
        runTestContinuously(new recurringTestA());
    }
}
```

```
public class recurringTestA {
    // some load tests that accesses resourceMap.get(A)

}
```

```
public class testContainerB extends someExternalClass {
    public void initialize() {
        databaseHelper.getResoucefromDB(B)
        runTestContinuously(new recurringTestB());
    }
}
```

```
public class recurringTestB {
    // some different load tests that accesses resourceMap.get(B)
}
```

```
public class databaseHelper{
    public static HashMap<String, List<resource>> resourceMap;
    public void getResoucefromDB(String resourceType) {
        resourceList.put(resourceType, callDatabase(resourceType));
    }
}
```

Requirements:

1. recurringTest constructor cannot have any parameters.
2. cannot use any files to save the resource list.
3. recurringTestA and recurringTestB are set up such that they run simultaenously

I tried saving the resources in a file and it works. I do not want to use any file though. How do I cache/save the resources so that it can be accessed inside the test without calling the database more than once?
How do I save resources in resourceList so that the recurring tests can access it without having to call DB again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will be a bad answer, but you can try to use static variables for this.